# Refining Text Search Results in MongoDB 5.0 - Specificity Over General Matches

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework, lucene

I am presently working with a MongoDB 5.0 collection in which data is organized in the given format:

```json
{
    "_id": "<id>",
    "name": "James Smith",
    "aliases": [
        "Jimmy Smith",
        "Jammy Smith",
        "Johnny Smith"
    ]
}
```

This collection houses in excess of 100k similar entries. I've constructed a text search index to enable effective querying:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "fields": {
            "aliases": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "storedSource": {
        "include": [
            "aliases",
            "names",
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to query this index, my code runs the following operation:

```json
[
    {
        "$search": {
            "index": "my-index",
            "text": {
                "query": "<NAME>",
                "path": ["name", "aliases"],
            },
            "scoreDetails": true,
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$name",
            "aliases": "$aliases",
            "score": {"$meta": "searchScore"}
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort": {
            "score": -1
        }
    }
]
```

The problem I'm encountering is when I search for a term like `"Gunther Lopez Smith"`, it's returning results including `"James Smith"`. Additionally, the search seems to be yielding all the records with "Smith", rounding up to 2k results.

While I'm using the `lucene.standard` analyzer, I experimented with `lucene.keyword` but it led to no returns for a query like "Smith James" and also seemed to impose case-sensitivity.

My goal is to fine-tune the search so that a query for `"Johnny Smith"` would return `"James Smith"` along with other related results such as `"smith James"`, but not all the entries with "Smith". Could anyone suggest a way to achieve this specific search result behavior?

Thanks for your help!